# Proof verification: $A=PR$, $A$ independent columns implies $R$ invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, solution-verification, matrix-decomposition

> **Given:**
>
> 1. $A$: $k \times n$-matrix with independent columns,
> 2. $R$: $n \times n$-matrix,
> 3. $A=PR$, where $P$ is a matrix.
>
> **Question:** Prove that $R$ is invertible.

**My proof:** Since $A$ has independent columns, we know that there exists a $QR$-factorization for $A$. Let $A=QR_{1}$ be the $QR$ factorization for $A$, so $PR=QR_{1}$. Since $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix, per definition of $QR$-factorization: $Q^{T}Q=I$. So:

$PR=QR_{1}$ iff $Q^{T}PR=R_{1}$ iff $Q^{T}PRR_{1}^{-1}=I$  (per def. of $QR$ factorisation is $R_{1}$ invertible).

Now note: $Q^{T}P$ and $RR_{1}^{-1}$ are both $n \times n$ matrices and their product is equal to the identity matrix. So:

$\operatorname{Det}(Q^{T}PRR_{1}^{-1})=1$ iff $\operatorname{Det}(Q^{T}P)\operatorname{Det}(RR_{1}^{-1})=1$ this means that $\operatorname{Det}(RR_{1}^{-1}) \neq 0 $.
Since $R$ and $R_{1}$ are both $n \times n$ matrices we can write:
$\operatorname{Det}(RR_{1}^{-1})=\operatorname{Det}(R)\operatorname{Det}(R_{1}^{-1}) \neq 0$, so $Det(R) \neq 0$, which means that $R$ is invertible.

> Are there any errors in my proof?

Comment: I think this proof is wrong. You assumed $R_1$ to be invertible, but if $A = QR_1$, then $R_1$ is in general not invertible. $R_1$ happens to be invertible iff $A$ is invertible, but this is in your situation only the case if $k = n$.

Comment: As $A$ is not a square matrix in general, the determinant of $R_1$ may be not even defined.

Comment: @Jan That is wrong, with QR-factorisation is R an invertible upper-triangle matrix thats how it is defined

Comment: Definitely not. $R$ has the same shape as $A$. Now take $A$ to be non-quadratic. In connection with this, note the comment of @InsideOut.